# Producing comprehensible logs for shell script ran through xargs

Tags: bash, logging

I am currently reindexing Elasticsearch indices in a shell script using curl to do REST API calls.

To improve performance, I am running this script with xargs over 10 processes.

However, all of my scripts are outputting into a single log, making this log useless/incomprehensible, since output is being written async which makes the log unordered.

The client would like to know progress made on reindexing by looking at logs (i.e they want to know if 50/100 index is done when they look at the log). And we would like to have the curl outputs etc for debugging purposes.

What are some ways I can make comprehensible logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try specifying a separate log file for each process, then concatenating the logs at the end.

But if you really want them all to access the same logfile, then I'm afraid your only way to do that is with a lock, which is not easy with bash/xargs.